# How can write python code to take input from user via bash script

Tags: python, bash, user-input

I want to calculate some measures for different cities and for each city 5 times. I need to give data via a bash script.

```
 #!/bin/bash 
 cities=('paris''helsinki' 'rome') 
 for city in "${cities[@]}" do
         for (( i = 1; i <= 5; i++ ))
         do
                 srun python3 random_graph.py  "$city" > "$city"/"city"_"$i".json
         done
```

done

I wrote my python code like this:

```
 def get_network_measure(city):
        some code
 
 if __name__ == '__main__':
       city = input()
       result = get_network_measure(city)
```

but I need to give the city name at the same time, not giving in the second step by input() function.
I need something like this when I run in bash

```
python mycode.py paris
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to read from arguments passed to the interpreter. These are available in [**`sys.argv`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.argv).

You also need to write to the standard output, [**`sys.stdout`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.stdout). You can do this by default using `print`:

```
import sys

def main(argv):
    city = argv[1]
    print(get_network_measure(city))

def get_network_measure(city):
    return 110


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(sys.argv)
```

You could also pipe input in using [**`sys.stdin`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.stdin).

Answer (score 0):

Python module [argparse](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/argparse.html) provides a convenient functionality for parsing command line arguments:

```
import argparse

def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('-c', '--city', 
                        help = 'name of the city', 
                        required = True
                        )
                       
    args = parser.parse_args()
    
    result = get_network_measure(args.city)
```

In bash you would have to do:

```
$ python mycode.py -c paris
```